# Como colocar espaço num Results? (NodeJS + JSON + MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

Olá, boa tarde!

Meu objetivo é acessar um MYSQL que possui colunas com **nomes compostos**. Atualmente, o código funciona para nomes simples (Codigo), mas o nome real da coluna é **Codigo do Cliente**. Alguém sabe como proceder?

```
connection.query(query, function (error, results, fields) {
 if (error) throw error;
 connection.end();
 var puxarid = '';
 puxarid = 'ID: '+results[0].Codigo;
 response.json({"fulfillmentText": puxarid })
```

Answer (score -1):

Me passaram a solução. Vou postar aqui pra ajudar a outros:

```
connection.query(query, function (error, results, fields) {
 if (error) throw error;
 connection.end();
 var puxarid = '';
 puxarid = 'ID: '+results[0]['Código do Cliente'];
 response.json({"fulfillmentText": puxarid })
```